# Can/should I nest the html abbr tag within a link?

Tags: xhtml

I link to my CV with the following:

```
 <li><a href="http://example.com/cv">CV</a></li>
```

However, should I have/would you recommend I have:

```
 <li><a href="http://example.com/cv"><abbr title="Curriculum vitae">CV</abbr></a></li>
```

Is the nesting of those tags ok to do/semantically appropriate, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would totally do this, but I wouldn't stop there. I'd throw a little Microdata in there also, making it:

`<li><a href="http://example.com/cm" rel="me"><abbr title="Curriculm vitae">CV</abbr></a></li>`

I'd go one step further if you're using [hCard](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard) and add a `class="url"` but that's probably overkill for you. I'd definitely put the `rel="me"` in there though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can and this is the right way to do it.

Whether you **should** - that's up to your needs. It's not a must at all.